# Associative mapping in Stan using canonical regression approach

Tags: bayesian, stan, association-measure, canonical-correlation

I've got 19 independent plant observations that consist of roughly 300 binary (dichotomous) genetic marker sightings at particular loci and 30 continuous concentrations of different types of flavonoids.

My task is to map the genomic data with the flavonoid concentrations and learn the association between those two sets of variables.

Because the number of plants is small, I realize that full regression is out of question and I need a model that has radically fewer parameters than 330 squared. From my perspective, the canonical analysis is an obvious starting point.

Because the majority of the variables are binary, and the number of observations less than 20 I decided that this analysis calls for a Bayesian model,
where I can model the binary variables as quantized normal variables using latent thresholds, and correctly deal with large uncertainties in the estimates of the canonical coefficients. I intend to present the first few canonical variates as results, together with the posterior probability that factor loading exclude zero.

I do not have experience in doing statistical calculations in the field of genomics.
Before I start implementing the model, I would like to ask for your advice whether my approach is sound and if there are any already existing models that I could use for this type of analysis.